# VBA using Rows()

Tags: vba, excel, rows

I need syntax help on this one. I have created a integer variable called totalData to hold the # of rows with data. Now I want to format the rows, so I am using

Rows("5:totalData").Select But i cannot use the "totalData" in the rows function.

Can someone please help me figure out a way that I can select all of these rows so I can format them with the correct size and font.

THANKS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Rows("5:" & totalData).Select`

Note totalData must be > 0

Note I only added a note because stackoverflow said the answer was too short.

Comment: Awesome thank you that works. Any way I can do that with a range? something like Range ("A5:" & KtotalData)

Comment: Absolutely, as long as KtotalData is a string that stores a valid cell name.

Comment: Or `Range("A5:A" & KtotalData)`

Comment: I cant seem to figure it out. I need to select everything from A5 to K215, but the number 215 often changes with the amount of data. I hold that number in totalData, but cant figure out the generic way to put it in

Comment: Using @Reafidy's last example change the second A to K and remove the K from the front of totalData.

Comment: That works. Thank you. I also used this and it worked....Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(totalData, 11)).Select